# improve performance SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have the below code…

```
UPDATE  Sales
    SET MappingOrderID = CAST ([dbo].[fRemoveNonNumericCharacters] (ltrim(rtrim(ActualOrderNumber))) AS INT) 
    FROM    Sales
    where   isnumeric(ActualOrderNumber) = 1 
    and ActualOrderNumber not like '%.%' 
    and len(ActualOrderNumber) < 10
    and MappingOrderID is null
    and ActualOrderNumber is not null
    and ltrim(rtrim(ActualOrderNumber)) in  (select ltrim(rtrim(OrderID)) from  dbo.Orders)
```

The participating columns are:

From Sales:
MappingOrderId   INT
ActualOrderNumber  NVARCHAR (10)

From Orders:
OrderId   INT

This is legacy code, I am the DBA, I do not know why he/she used Trim so much… The script takes 9 minutes to run, and ideally has to be run frequently…

I also get this in the execution plan:

- CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[DataMart].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderID],0)
- CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(20),[Datamart].[dbo].[Sales].[ActualOrderNumber],0)
- Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(20),[DataMart].[dbo].[Sales].[ActualOrderNumber],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, Type conversion in expression (CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(12),[Datamart].[dbo].[Orders].[OrderID],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

For what I sense...

It Updates MappingOrderId (int) by casting ActualOrderNumber (varchar)... It will update only if ActualOrderNumber exists in Orders...

I try a few modfiications; but the varchar ActualOrderNumber  has values like 3545427103, and if I try to remove anything like:

```
and len(ActualOrderNumber) < 10
```

It will break…

My overall goal is to make this process the most efficient possible; is fixing the data at source the only real solution?

I implemented many of the suggestions and it went down to a minute. Thanks! But what I do not understand is this:

Before, with the ugly code I had:
[image]

Now I have MORE reads… and it takes seconds to run… how is this possible?
[image]

Comment: LIKE is also very expensive. There are surely ways to improve this query if you know the logic. Is that a check for a dollar value in the order number field? That could be changed to CONTAINS. What's up with returning only the order numbers with a length less than 10 also?

Comment: If you have the opportunity, add a column that contains the cleaned order number to both tables, populate it and index it. The time taken in total may or may not be less than nine minutes. You might also see some advantage in changing the final `IN` to an `exists`, but check the query plan between changes.

Comment: Oh and you also have a UDF there which could be slowing things down. The query plan should give you some idea. To work out if the CardinalityEstimate has actually been affected, compare actual and estimated plans and see whether row counts are in the same vicinity

Comment: I added extra information in the post...

Comment: And I change the code to: update Sales
 set  MappingOrderID = ActualOrderNumber
 from Sales
 where isnumeric(ActualOrderNumber) = 1 
 and  len(ActualOrderNumber) < 10
 and  MappingOrderID is null
 and  ActualOrderNumber in (select OrderID from dbo.Orders)

(its MUCH faster, but again,somehow it reads more?!)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  Sales
SET MappingOrderID = CAST (ltrim(rtrim(ActualOrderNumber)) AS INT) 
FROM    Sales S
inner join dbo.Orders O on ltrim(rtrim(O.OrderID))=ltrim(rtrim(s.ActualOrderNumber))
where   isnumeric(ActualOrderNumber) = 1 
and ActualOrderNumber not like '%.%' 
and len(ActualOrderNumber) < 10
and MappingOrderID is null
```

**Changes**

**1. Removed function "fRemoveNonNumericCharacters"**

- As you are checking isnumeric in where clause, there is no need to use this function.

**2. Joined sales and orders table**

- if you will use orders table in where clause as you have mentioned, then for each row of sales table, complete Orders table will be rendered.
- To reduce this process, I have added join.

**3. removed ActualOrderNumeric is not null**

- As you are checking isnumeric in where clause, there is no need to use this condition. Because for null, isnumeric will return 0.

Comment: Could probably add "and CONTAINS(ActualOrderNumber, '.')" Which should be more efficient than the NOT LIKE clause. Hopefully these columns are indexed.